# DbUpdate Exception on RemoveRange

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to purge a table, however, when I do I get a `DbUpdateException`. I'm uncertain what is causing this as there are no foreign key constraints.

### Calling Code Below

```
    /* Get the context */ 
    NLISdBContext databaseContext = contextFactory.GetNLISdBContext();

    /* Remove the data */ 
    databaseContext.Picexceptions.RemoveRange(databaseContext.Picexceptions);
    databaseContext.SaveChanges(); // <-- Error Here
```

### Possible Cause

There is a single Contraint on the table, which may be causing it, but I am unsure as to why it would. See constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT [filteredPIC_ProgramCode_ExceptionStatus_IDX] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PIC] ASC,
    [ProgramCode] ASC,
    [ExceptionStatus] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

My reasoning is that if a line is removed, it shouldn't violate the constraint. Could it be that If am removing all of them it causes issues with the cluster index?

If not that, what are some other common causes of this exception?

### Exception

```
NLISLib.DataSources.NLISdBContext_PrimaryDataSource Encountered exception in PurgePICExceptions: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor encountered an unexpected error during execution (HRESULT = 0x80040e19).
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreResults(Boolean& moreResults)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryNextResult(Boolean& more)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.NextResult()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at NLISLib.DataSources.NLISdBContext_PrimaryDataSource.PurgePICExceptions()
```

Comment: If you are removing all records have you considered issuing a direct DELETE command against the database? It would be faster too.

Comment: @mjwills, I did not, but I will and see if it works. Why would it be faster?

Comment: The code, as is, seems to me like it would need to pull all the data down _then_ delete it. A single DELETE step avoids querying it out first.

Comment: Can you  delete the data in SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var removedItems=databaseContext.Picexceptions.ToArray();
databaseContext.Picexceptions.RemoveRange(removedItems);
 databaseContext.SaveChanges();
```

but something tells me that this will be more efficient if db has a lot of records

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE [Picexceptions]");
```

or you can try Database.ExecuteSqlCommand. it depends on the version.

Comment: See the inner exception. The code doesn't fail and doesn't need fixing. SQL server fails in a way that may even indicate data corruption.